# Typescript How to declare a subclass type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to have something like this?

```
export abstract class FilterBoxElement {
    abstract getEntities: any;
}
export interface FilterBoxControlSuggestions extends FilterBoxElement {
    getEntities: // some implementation with different parameters
}
export interface FilterBoxControlDropDown extends FilterBoxElement {
    getEntities: // some implementation with different parameters
}

export interface FilterBoxDataProps {
    controlElement: FilterBoxElement // FilterBoxControlSuggestions or FilterBoxControlDropDown 
}
```

I want that `controlElement` has to be a `FilterBoxControlSuggestions` or a `FilterBoxControlDropDown`. But right now I can put everything in it. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it with a union type:

```js
export interface FilterBoxDataProps {
    controlElement: FilterBoxControlSuggestions | FilterBoxControlDropDown 
}
```

Or with generics if you want all subclasses of FilterBoxElement:

```js
export interface FilterBoxDataProps<T extends FilterBoxElement> {
    controlElement: T
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it can be one type or the other, use a union type (`|`):

```
export interface FilterBoxDataProps {
    controlElement: FilterBoxControlSuggestions | FilterBoxControlDropDown;
}
```